# how to display list of records in modal popup?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have button on lightning component.
Clicking the button should open the modal dialog which has List of records of the account.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You should implement your own custom component - try out the Strike library with the  [Modal](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeModal) and the [DataGrid](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeDataGrid) components - it should be a big help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take a look at the SLDS [modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/), in order to populate it with your requirements.

You can then use an [object attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_object_salesforce.htm) for your Account records and in your lightning controller, you can call your server side action to fetch Account records when your modal pops up -> [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm)

In the future, make sure you include what you have tried alongside any relevant code and mention where you are stuck or what you fail to understand.